# Why does AddWithValue() work without @?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters

Why does my code work when i use:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", user);
```

when it should be (according to the internet):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
```

Does the method support the parameter name without the @?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, boths are equivalent for .NET apps interfacing with SQL Server.

I personally use the notation with the `@` sign myself.

Comment: so do we need to use @ while interacting with other database systems like My-SQL,Oracle?

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi There is no **have to**, I don't think so. In my opinion, people are use `@` with `AddWithValue` method because it is familiar with parameterizing store procedures.